# Adding data's to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My name is Gokul and I work for Blackboard (Virtual Learning Environment). I have got a new requirement in my organization where I need to work on Rails Application and I am facing some challenges in storing data to the model, where I need some help. I am new to Rails and so please apologize if my question sounds dumb.

We have an instance method (student_mark) which takes an argument as an input and generates Array of Hash.

```
=> "[{\"TT (Theory Total)\":{\"Mathematics\":\"89.35\",\"Physics\":\"125.5\",\"Biology\":\"96.2\",\"Data Entry Operations\":\"49.5\",\"Chemistry\":\"35.55\",\"Sanskrit\":\"40.25\"},\"PT (Practical Total)\":{\"Physics\":\"150.55\",\"Library and Information Science\":\"177.85\",\"Chemistry\":\"125.55\",\"Home Science\":\"165.45\",\"Geography\":\"188.30\",\"Computer Science\":\"195.55\"}},{\"TT (Theory Total)\":{\"Mathematics\":\"69.35\",\"Physics\":\"127.5\",\"Biology\":\"196.2\",\"Data Entry Operations\":\"99.5\",\"Chemistry\":\"87.55\",\"Sanskrit\":\"89.25\"},\"PT (Practical Total)\":{\"Physics\":\"189.55\",\"Library and Information Science\":\"198.85\",\"Chemistry\":\"145.55\",\"Home Science\":\"145.45\",\"Geography\":\"132.30\",\"Computer Science\":\"112.55\"}}]"
```

**#New Update**

As of now, I do something like the following and get the below results.

```
VLE :028 > theory_total_params = parsed[0]["TT (Theory Total)"].inject({}) do |to_return ,v|
VLE :029 >     to_return[v[0].gsub(" ","_").downcase.to_sym] = v[1].to_f
VLE :030?>   to_return
VLE :031?>   end
 => {:mathematics=>89.35, :physics=>125.5, :biology=>96.2, :data_entry_operations=>49.5, :chemistry=>35.55, :sanskrit=>40.25}

VLE :032 > theory_total_params = parsed[1]["TT (Theory Total)"].inject({}) do |to_return ,v|
VLE :033 >     to_return[v[0].gsub(" ","_").downcase.to_sym] = v[1].to_f
VLE :034?>   to_return
VLE :035?>   end
 => {:mathematics=>69.35, :physics=>127.5, :biology=>196.2, :data_entry_operations=>99.5, :chemistry=>87.55, :sanskrit=>89.25}
```

My end goal is to store the above results into a model. With the above thing, it is not possible to store all the values. So I believe we need to iterate over the arrays to get all the results. Can someone help me here on how we can achieve it?

Comment: Can you list out what exactly the problem you are facing? What have you tried to store the data and where are you getting an issue?

Comment: Does it *always* return an array of hashes? Or does it *sometimes* return an array of hashes and *sometimes* return a hash?

Comment: @jvillian, so it always returns array of hashes.

Comment: Ok. Hang on, working on it now.

Comment: Yes, but I've never used freenode IRC. Explain how to do it, and I can chat.

Comment: @jvillian, hope you are doing good. Do you have few minutes of time? Encountering some issues in storing the  content. It would be great help, if we can get into quick chat if you have some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
student_ids = [8, 10]
```

Do something like:

```
student_ids.each do |student_id|                                      # for each student you're interested in...
  score_set_hsh = JSON.parse(student_mark(student_id))                # get the score_set_hash from your student_mark method
  [                                                                   # convenience array to avoid repetition in following code
    ["TT (Theory Total)", TheoryTotal],
    ["PT (Practical Total)", PracticalTotal]
  ].each do |extract_ary|                                             # iterate the convenience array
    score_total_key   = extract_ary[0]                                # assign score_total_key, e.g.: "TT (Theory Total)"
    score_total_klass = extract_ary[1]                                # assign score_total_klass, e.g.: TheoryTotal
    score_set_hsh[score_total_key]                                    # grab one of the score total hashes
      .each_with_object({}) do |raw_score_ary, to_return|             # iterate through its elements
        score_key = raw_score_ary[0].gsub(" ","_").downcase.to_sym    # grab the element key, e.g.: :mathematics
        score_value = raw_score_ary[1].to_f                           # grab the element value, e.g.: 89.35
        to_return[score_key] = score_value                            # assign the element value to the return hash using the key
      end.
      merge!(student_id: student_id).                                 # add the student id
      tap do |formatted_score_hsh|
        new_score = score_total_klass.new(formatted_score_hsh)        # instantiate the new record
        if new_score.valid?                                           # check if valid
          new_score.save.tap do |save_result|                         # save if valid
            puts "save_result: #{save_result}"                        # some outputs just to look at things
            puts "new_score.inspect: #{new_score.inspect}"            
          end
        else
          #do some error handling                                     # if you have errors
        end
      end
  end
end
```

BTW, that method is sort of jenk because it doesn't return the student_id that was passed in which means you have to do some extra gymnastics to match up the student results with the student id. If you can, you should refactor that method.

Comment: Please add to your question the output from console that identifies the line number with the error and the code throwing the error.

Comment: Just do a test to see whether it's an array or a hash and then process accordingly.

Comment: Is this code in a controller? A model? A plain ruby object? Please post the class code in your original question and I'll show you how to do it.